# Magento 2 :get product image ,price and name

Tags: magento2, product, theme

I am new to Magento2 and working on the custom theme. I am trying to include product image,  price, and name but they are not displaying.

This is my code.

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $abstractProductBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct');
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->setPageSize(8)
                ->load();
?>

<div class="productinfo text-center">
          <?php foreach ($collection as $product) :?>
      <img src=<?php echo $abstractProductBlock->getImage($product, 'latest_collection_list')->getImageUrl(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
        <h2>$56</h2>
        <p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p>
         <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>"> class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
</div>
<div class="product-overlay">
    <div class="overlay-content">

 <h2><?php echo $abstractProductBlock->getProductPrice($product) ?></h2>
 <?php endforeach;  ?>
```

Products are not showing but there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use objectmanager it's not Magento standard.
Make one block and get the collection from there.

```
<?php
namespace Test\test\Block;
class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
protected $_imageHelper;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_imageHelper = $imageHelper;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(3);        
    return $collection;
}
public function getImageUrl($product) {
    $image_url = $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize(200, 200)->getUrl();
    return $image_url;
}
```

?>

Now you can get your collection in your template file like test.phtml below.

```
<?php
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {    
    echo $product->getName().' => ';    
    echo $product->getPrice().' => ';
    echo $block->getImageUrl($product);
    echo '<br>';
}
die;
?>
```

Still if you facing any problem let me know.

Comment: no sir this is not working

Comment: @shohel Please check my updated code